# Where does Internet Explorer store the last used upload directory?

Tags: shell, windows-explorer, internet-explorer, windows-registry

I have an image of a user's hard drive from which I need to recover some photos, but I don't know the file names or directory they are stored in.

The photos are not in any of the typical profile folders. The user stated that the photos were always "just there" whenever they went to upload a file from Internet Explorer. Of course they don't know which folder it was... just that it was the one that comes up when you upload a file.

On my computer I created a folder with a unique name, uploaded a file from it using Internet Explorer and then searched through the registry but could not find any reference to the folder name.

Does anyone know how I can find the last used upload directory?

Comment: Why don't you just search by file extension?  I don't believe what you want to find is stored in the registry.

Comment: I tried reopening IE after uploading a file, and open dialog starts browsing form the desktop. It may be that this information is actually only stored in RAM and not saved between sessions. If it was always "just there" you might want to look in the desktop folder. Also, it might help to add which version of Windows and IE was used. (I tested on Windows 7 using IE11.)

Answer (score 0):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` key `Default Download Directory`

This saves both, Default One, and in case you have Default one disabled - last one.